# Filter a list of tuples on the longest item in the tuple

Tags: python

Say I have this data

```
my_list_of_tuples = [
    ('bill', [(4, ['626']), (4, ['253', '30', '626']),
              (4, ['253', '30', '626']), (4, ['626']),
              (4, ['626']), (4, ['626'])]),
    ('sarah', [(2, ['6']), (2, ['2', '6']), (2, ['2', '6']),
               (2, ['6']), (2, ['6']), (2, ['6'])]),
    ('fred', [(1, ['6']), (1, ['2']), (1, ['2'])])
]
```

And I want to keep out all the items that are longest in a sub-tuple list element, and duplicates are removed, so that I am left with

```
my_output_list_of_tuples = [
    ('bill',  [(4, ['253', '30', '626'])]),
    ('sarah',  [(2, ['2', '6'])]),
    ('fred',  [(1, ['6']), (1, ['2'])])]
```

So far I tried

```
my_output_list_of_tuples = [(x[0], max(x[1], key=lambda tup: len(tup[1]))) for x in my_list_of_tuples]
```

but that does not work for fred, because the max function only returns one item. I also tried a few map attempts and lamba but got less far.

I'm OK to break it up like

```
for my_list_of_tuples_by_person_name in my_list_of_tuples:
    #Do something with my_list_of_tuples_by_person_name[1]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For a more complex problem, the usual approach is to write up the code as nested loops first, then reduce that code to the one-line expression.  Can you code the logic in multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max`:

```
my_list_of_tuples = my_list_of_tuples = [('bill', [(4, ['626']), (4, ['253', '30', '626']), (4, ['253', '30', '626']), (4, ['626']), (4, ['626']), (4, ['626'])]), ('sarah', [(2, ['6']), (2, ['2', '6']), (2, ['2', '6']), (2, ['6']), (2, ['6']), (2, ['6'])]), ('fred', [(1, ['6']), (1, ['2']), (1, ['2'])])]
final_result = [(a, [(c, d) for c, d in b if len(d) == max(map(len, [h for _, h in b]))]) for a, b in my_list_of_tuples]
new_result = [(a, [c for i, c in enumerate(b) if c not in b[:i]]) for a, b in final_result]
```

Output:

```
[('bill', [(4, ['253', '30', '626'])]), ('sarah', [(2, ['2', '6'])]), ('fred', [(1, ['6']), (1, ['2'])])]
```

Comment: So graceful. Works great.  Thank you.

Comment: @Joylove Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve duplicates like this, you can't just call `max`, you have to compare each value to the result of `max`.

The most readable way to do this is probably to build a dict mapping keys to max lengths, and then compare each tuple against that:

```
result = []
for name, sublist in my_list_of_tuples:
    d = {}
    for key, subsub in sublist:
        if len(subsub) > d.get(key, 0):
            d[key] = len(subsub)
    lst =[(key, subsub) for key, subsub in sublist if len(subsub) == d[key]]
    result.append((name, lst))
```

You can condense most parts of this down, but it'll probably only make things more opaque and less maintainable. And notice that the naive way to condense a two-pass loop into a single expression (where you calculate `max` each time through) converts it into a nested (quadratic) loop, so it's going to be even more verbose than you think.

---

Since you've completely changed the problem and now apparently want only the longest sublist (presumably picking arbitrarily when there are duplicates, or non-duplicate-but-same-length values?), things are simpler:

```
result = []
for name, sublist in my_list_of_tuples:
    keysubsub = max(sublist, key=lambda keysubsub: len(keysubsub[1]))
    result.append((name, keysubsub))
```

But that's basically what you already had. You say the problem with it is "… but that does not work for fred, because the max function only returns one item", but I'm not sure what you want *instead* of one item.

---

If what you're looking for is all *distinct* lists of the maximum length, you can use a `set` or `OrderedSet` instead of a `list` in the first answer. There's no `OrderedSet` in the stdlib, but [this recipe by Raymond Hettinger](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/576696_OrderedSet_with_Weakrefs/README.md) should be fine for our purposes. But let's do it manually with a set and a list:

```
result = []
for name, sublist in my_list_of_tuples:
    d = {}
    for key, subsub in sublist:
        if len(subsub) > d.get(key, 0):
            d[key] = len(subsub)
    lst, seen = [], set()
    for key, subsub in sublist:
        if len(subsub) == d[key] and tuple(subsub) not in seen:
            seen.add(tuple(subsub))
            lst.append((key, subsub))
    result.append((name, lst))
```

I think this last one provides exactly the output your updated question asks, and doesn't do anything hard to understand to get there.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question.  I want to preserve items of the same length, I had it confused in my mind as I was working on the problem, that preserve ing duplicates had the desired effect.

Comment: @Joylove I can't figure out what your desired output is from your description. It seems like you're asking how to turn what you originally had into exactly what you originally had?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I am looking for the unique supersets.

Comment: @Joylove OK, I've updated by answer again. But the goal of these answers is for you to learn how they work, not just copy and paste them. If this isn't simpler enough for you to understand and make minor changes to it, please explain what part is too complicated.

Comment: Thank you I do understand what you are doing here, assembling a dict of the longest lengths, using that to populate 'seen' and this is the answer to the method of looping through the list that I didn't have.

Comment: @Joylove While we're at it, you may also want to look at some of the recipes in the `itertrools` docs—e.g., the `unique_everseen` that generalizes (and serves as a great example of) what I'm doing with that `seen` set. I'm not sure how familiar you are with the iterator transform pipeline style, but see [Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) for a great introduction) if the answer is "not at all". That's the direction I'd go in simplifying this, once I got it working. (Or, rather, I'd write it in that style in the first place.)

Comment: Since I have need to work on the key of subsub also, I went with this approach.  Thank you @abarnert

Answer (score 1):

First you define a function

```
def f(ls):
    max_length = max(len(y) for (x, y) in ls)

    result = []

    for (x, y) in ls:
        if len(y) == max_length and (x, y) not in result:
            result.append((x, y))

    return result
```

Now call it like this

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([(name, f(y)) for name, y in my_list_of_tuples])
[('bill', [(4, ['253', '30', '626'])]),
 ('sarah', [(2, ['2', '6'])]),
 ('fred', [(1, ['6']), (1, ['2'])])]
```